# I have a light on my dashboard and am told it's gearbox oil which I am not sure of. Need your help please

Tags: honda

[image] I have this light on in my Honda fit but I do not know what to do. Need your help please.

Answer (score 1):

Yep, that means the gearbox oil is due for replacement. It comes on after the appropriate distance interval since the last change has been covered, if I recall correctly the number indicates how far over the interval you've driven. If I'm right on that I think you need to get the fluid changed ASAP, 4600km over is **really** far!